# How to use tabhost for Single activity in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, tabs

want to use tab host to make my page more flexible ..Here is my case 
for example I have student information form with scrolable enough controls so want to divide page in tabs .

1. Tab 1 will have student personal details such as name age DOB etc
2. Tab 2 will have Students School details such as school nm,std,subjects
3. Tab 3 will have he is co-curricular activity details such as achievements,interests-hobbies

previously it was in one page only ;having code in one activity and submit button click will save the page in one DB table named studentTbl.sqlite

now want to use 3 tabs each with next button and end tab will have submit button which will save all 3 tabs data on save click in studentTbl.sqlite

so how can i implement tab host for this kind of single page activity for Single table save ?

Comment: to do this you have to take global variable for each class, then on next button's click event get the value of your text field's and store it in global variable and then at last on submit button's click event fire it to Database.

Comment: but should i make different activity call for each tab or is it possible to make in single activity?

Comment: You can make it a single activity and use fragments for the views.

Comment: it's up to you. What is your task?, you can do both the things.

Comment: Yes, @Leco is right. you can do in that way also.

Comment: @Leco.. thnk u @ Innocent Killer ...ok want to keep it simple to understand & easy to implement & also if any code snippet thr then just post it here

Comment: @Leco ...and @ Innocent Killer please provide me some code scrip lets if possible

Comment: here i got one more link which is easy to learn [GitHub link](https://github.com/nheid/unitedcoders-android/blob/master/src/com/unitedcoders/android/examples/Tabs.java)

Answer (score 2):

Create one new activity **Const.java** and add below code.

```
public class Const {
    public static String name;
    public static String age;
    public static String dob;
    public static String schoolname;
    public static String std;
    public static String sub;
             ...
             ...
}
```

Now inside first activities next button click event use below code.

```
next.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

           Code.name= editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
           Code.age= editTextAge.getText().toString().trim();
                  .......
                  .......
        }
   });
```

and then same for all activity (Second activity) and also you can add more screen if you want to add then at last screen's submit button get this all global variable value and pass it to database.

Hope it will help you. And let me know still if you have any problem...

Answer (score 0):

this sample code may help you...

```
public class SecondActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private static final int CONTENT_ID = 0xFEED;

    private Fragment tab1Fragment;
    private Fragment tab2Fragment;
    private Fragment tab3Fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(getContentView());
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        tab1Fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
        tab2Fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
        tab3Fragment = new Tab3Fragment();

        initActionBar();
    }

    private void initActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1")
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2")
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3")
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    private View getContentView() {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(CONTENT_ID);
        return frameLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(CONTENT_ID, tab1Fragment);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(CONTENT_ID, tab2Fragment);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(CONTENT_ID, tab3Fragment);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    public static class StudentInfo {
        public static String NAME;
        public static String LOCATION;
        public static String SCHOOL_NAME;
        public static String COLLEGE_NAME;
        public static String COMPANY;
        public static String JOB;
    }

    public static abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements
            View.OnClickListener {

        protected EditText editText1;
        protected EditText editText2;
        protected Button nextButton;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_activity_layout, container,
                    false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            editText1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            editText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
            nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadValues();
        }

        protected abstract void loadValues();
    }

    public static class Tab1Fragment extends BaseFragment {

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText("Name");
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText("Location");
        }

        @Override
        protected void loadValues() {
            StudentInfo.NAME = editText1.getText().toString();
            StudentInfo.LOCATION = editText2.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    public static class Tab2Fragment extends BaseFragment {

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText("School");
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText("College");
        }

        @Override
        protected void loadValues() {
            StudentInfo.SCHOOL_NAME = editText1.getText().toString();
            StudentInfo.COLLEGE_NAME = editText2.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    public static class Tab3Fragment extends BaseFragment {

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText("Company");
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText("Job");
        }

        @Override
        protected void loadValues() {
            StudentInfo.COMPANY = editText1.getText().toString();
            StudentInfo.JOB = editText2.getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is second_activity_layout.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Label"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Label"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Next"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```